# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException for HibernateTemplate class Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring

While Integrating the Spring with Hibernate getting above exception along with below logs. Attached all necessary files below please let me know if you need any thing. FYI : I am using below jars.

[image]

**Error Log**

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [HibernateApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [HibernateApplicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>               
> at com.SpringIntegrationWithHibernate.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:18)
>           Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [HibernateApplicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1303)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
>               ... 10 more
>           Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295)
>               ... 18 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException
>               
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>               
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
>               
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
>               
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
>               
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
>               ... 19 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.JDBCException
>               
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>               
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>               
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>               
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>               ... 24 more

### Main Class

```
    package com.SpringIntegrationWithHibernate;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
    import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
    import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

    public class MainClass {



        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Resource r=new ClassPathResource("HibernateApplicationContext.xml");  
            BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

            EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");  

            Employees e=new Employees();  
            e.setId(114);  
            e.setFirstName("Varun");  
            e.setLastName("Dhawan");  

            dao.saveEmployee(e);

        }

    }
```

### Hibernate Mapping Xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.SpringIntegrationWithHibernate.Employees"
            table="Employees_Spring">
            <id name="id">
                <generator class="assigned"></generator>
            </id>

            <property name="FirstName"></property>
            <property name="LastName"></property>
        </class>

    </hibernate-mapping>
```

## Employee DAO class ##

```
    package com.SpringIntegrationWithHibernate;


    import java.util.*;

    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;




    public class EmployeeDao {  
    HibernateTemplate template;  
    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
        this.template = template;  
    }  
    //method to save employee  
    public void saveEmployee(Employees e){  
        template.save(e);  
    }  
    //method to update employee  
    public void updateEmployee(Employees e){  
    //    template.update(e);  
    }  
    //method to delete employee  
    public void deleteEmployee(Employees e){  
    //    template.delete(e);  
    }  
    //method to return one employee of given id  
    //public Employees getById(int id){  
    //    Employees e=(Employees)template.get(Employees.class,id);  
    //    return e;  
    //}  
    //method to return all employees  
    public List<Employees> getEmployees(){  
        List<Employees> list=new ArrayList<Employees>();  
        list=template.loadAll(Employees.class);  
        return list;  
    }  
    }
```

## Application context XML ##

```
    <beans  
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
            <property name="driverClassName"  value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>  
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>  
            <property name="username" value="hr"></property>  
            <property name="password" value="umashetti123"></property>  
        </bean>  

        <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

            <property name="mappingResources">  
            <list>  
            <value>Employees.hbm.xml</value>  
            </list>  
            </property>  

            <property name="hibernateProperties">  
                <props>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

                </props>  
            </property>  
        </bean>  

        <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
        </bean>  

        <bean id="d" class="com.SpringIntegrationWithHibernate.EmployeeDao">  
        <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
        </bean>  


        </beans>
```

### Employee Persistence class

```
    package com.SpringIntegrationWithHibernate;

    public class Employees {


        private int id;
        private String FirstName;
        private String LastName;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return FirstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            FirstName = firstName;
        }


        public String getLastName() {
            return LastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            LastName = lastName;
        }

        public Employees() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }
```

Please help me out solving this issue.

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring 5.1, 3.0 and 3.1 jars in a single project. That is trouble waiting to happen. This probably comes from the fact that you don't use something like Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies and build and you are searching the internet yourself for jars. I strongly suggest to use a dependency manager like Maven or Gradle to make your life easier.

Comment: No one uses XML configuration anymore.  Add appropriate annotations.  Why Hibernate for such a simple object?  Start with JdbcTemplate.  Hibernate is overkill squared.

Comment: Also Spring 5 doesn't support hibernate 3 so you need to upgrade your hibernate version as well. Or you are trying to use Hibernate 5 (the Spring 5.1 supported version) with Hibernate 3 support classes.